# Game maps with "counties" that are split along lines that aren't necessarily straight

Tags: xna, maps, windows-phone-7

I want to create a game environment that supports a 2D map.  This is a really basic map, but must be split along lines that are not necessarily straight.  So imagine a country with county boundaries.  I then want to be able to detect drag / drop events within these counties.

What I'm really looking for here is a pointer to where to start on this (how it has been done before - any existing libraries out there), as I'm sure that what I'm trying to do is not new - although I can't find a beginners guide for this anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two general approaches I would take.

1) The polygon-based approach.  Each of your zones is defined as a series of points.  You can then do [point-in-polygon testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) for whether or not your cursor position is inside a given area.  You can also do things like tessellate it and draw an image on it.

2) The image-based approach.  Author an image where a specific pixel color represents a certain area. Kind of like how [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24058/defining-and-selecting-an-area-from-an-image) does.  Then you do a check in the image pixel data for what color you're currently selecting to determine which zone you're in.

Answer (score 1):

Amit Patel has some great information on polygonal map generation here:
http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/

He uses random points and generates a Voronoi diagram from those, and from there you can coalesce adjacent polygons to form county boundaries. Each of the original polygons is convex so checking a mouse click within them is fairly simple.